# ASP.NET MVC jQuery JSON result redirecting URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC/Json/Jquery.
Using form to create a new "group".
Form is on ~Group/Manage,  posting form to ~Group/Create
Whilst working on this, returning Json result was working fine, handling in Jquery, no URL redirection.
Now, everytime I run it, it redirects me to ~Group/Create and displays the Json result.

Controller Group/Create

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="name,description")] GroupModel groupmodel)
    {
      ...
      return Json(new { success = true, message = groupmodel.name }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Form

```
 <form id="frm_createGroup" action="/Groups/Create" method="post">
            <h2>Create Group</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, new { @for = "name" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Group Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.description, new { @for = "description" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.description, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Group Description" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description)
            </div>
            <span id="createGroupMessage"></span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Create</button>

        </form>
```

Jquery to handle form

```
        $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#navGroups').makeActiveMenuItem();
        var options = {
             success: groupCreateSubmitted
            ,error: groupCreateError
        }
        $('#frm_createGroup').ajaxForm(options);
    });

    function groupCreateSubmitted(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        if (responseText.success)
        {
            $('#createGroupMessage').html = "Group Created";
        }
        else
        {
            $('#createGroupMessage').html = responseText.message;
        }

    }
```

To be clear, I don't want URL redirection, I just want the Jquery to catch the return (it was before, have no idea why its changed...)

Thanks!

Comment: Clearly its doing a normal submit. What plugin are you using and what if any errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: using jquery form plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ ), can't see any errors :( hmm I see its hanging on the external script reference to the form plugin, might try and get a local copy and see if that fixes it.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api), _".ajaxForm() prepares a form to be submitted via AJAX by adding all of the necessary event listeners. It does not submit the form"_. Have you included `ajaxSubmit()` in your code?

Comment: no, I followed the format of the above site I linked (the jquery plugin), everything was working fine, reducing code to bare bones and still can't get it to go back to behaviour of not redirecting...

Comment: Look at the link I gave in my last comment - I'm not familiar with that plugin but its seems you need to call `.ajaxSubmit()` - see the second example

Comment: Thanks for help stephen, will look at link, but solved problem :), the ",error: groupCreateError" was causing the form bind to fail (no idea why or where/if it was reporting this error. Removed it, and working again now. Thanks again for your help,the "clearly doing normal submit" comment pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Perhaps because you did not have a function named `groupCreateError`?

Comment: could be! I think i missed a  semi colon at the end of the options object too.1 hour wasted due to semi colon :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed
     ,error: groupCreateError

working now...form bind was failing.